# Make systemctl work from inside a container in a debian stretch image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, debian, systemd, kops

## Purpose - What do I want to achieve?

I want to access `systemctl` from inside a container running a kubernetes node (ami: running debian stretch)

## Working setup:

- [Node AMI](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/channels/stable#L22): kope.io/k8s-1.10-debian-jessie-amd64-hvm-ebs-2018-08-17
- Node Directories Mounted in the container to make `systemctl` work:

  - /var/run/dbus
  - /run/systemd
  - /bin/systemctl
  - /etc/systemd/system

## Not Working setup:

- [Node AMI](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/channels/stable#L26): kope.io/k8s-1.11-debian-stretch-amd64-hvm-ebs-2018-08-17
- Node Directories Mounted in the container to make `systemctl` work:

  - /var/run/dbus
  - /run/systemd
  - /bin/systemctl
  - /etc/systemd/system

## Debugging in an attempt to solve the problem

To debug this issue with the `debian-stretch` image not supporting `systemctl` with the same mounts as `debian-jessie`

1) I began by spinning up a nginx deployment by mounting the above mentioned volumes in it

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/application/deployment.yaml

kubectl exec -it nginx-deployment /bin/bash

root@nginx-deployment-788f65877d-pzzrn:/# systemctl
systemctl: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared- 
232.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

2) As the above issue showed the file `libsystemd-shared-232.so` not found. I found the actual path by looking into the node.

```
admin@ip-10-0-20-11:~$ sudo find / -iname 'libsystemd-shared-232.so'
/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-232.so
```

3) Mounted the `/lib/systemd` in the nginx pod and ran the systemctl again

```
 kubectl exec -it nginx-deployment /bin/bash

 root@nginx-deployment-587d866f54-ghfll:/# systemctl
 systemctl: error while loading shared libraries: libcap.so.2:cannot 
 open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

4) Now the `systemctl` was failing with a new so missing error

```
root@nginx-deployment-587d866f54-ghfll:/# systemctl
systemctl: error while loading shared libraries: libcap.so.2: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

5) To solve the above error i again searched the node for `libcap.so.2` Found it in the below path.

```
admin@ip-10-0-20-11:~$ sudo find / -iname 'libcap.so.2'
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2
```

6) Seeing the above directory not mounted in my pod. I mounted the below path in the nginx pod.

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu mounted in the nginx pod(deployment)
```

7) The nginx pod  is not able to come up after adding the above mount. Getting the below error:

```
$ k logs nginx-deployment-f9c5ff956-b9wn5
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file 
or directory"
```

Please suggest how to debug further. And what all mounts are required to make systemctl work from inside a container in a debian stretch environment.

Any pointers to take the debugging further could be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Rather than mounting some of the library files from the host you can just install `systemd` in the container.

```
$ apt-get -y install systemd
```

Now, that won't necessarily make `systemctl` run. You will need `systemd` to be running in your container which is spawned by `/sbin/init` on your system. `/sbin/init` needs to run as root so essentially you would have to run this with the `privileged` flag in the pod or container [security context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#securitycontext-v1-core) on Kubernetes. Now, this is insecure and [there is a long history](https://lwn.net/Articles/676831/) about running systemd in a container where the Docker folks were mostly against it (security) and the Red Hat folks said that it was needed.

Nevertheless, the Red Hat folks figured out a way to [make it work without the `unprivileged` flag](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/09/13/running-systemd-in-a-non-privileged-container/). You need:

- `/run` mounted as a tmpfs in the container.
- `/sys/fs/cgroup` mounted as read-only is ok.
- `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/` mounted as read/write.
- Use for `STOPSIGNAL` `SIGRTMIN+3`

In Kubernetes you need an [`emptyDir`](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/09/13/running-systemd-in-a-non-privileged-container/) to mount a `tmpfs`. The others can be mounted as host volumes.

Comment: Thanks Rico. For me it worked after insalling systemd in the container and mounting the directories i mentioned above in the question. I have not made the pod priveleged also. Confused why it works for me after reading your information above.

Answer (score 2):

After mounting your host's `/lib` directory into the container, your Pod most probably will not start because the Docker image's `/lib` directory contained some library needed by the Nginx server that should start in that container. By mounting `/lib` from the host, the libraries required by Nginx will not be accessible any more. This will result in a *No such file or directory* error when trying to start Nginx.

To make `systemctl` available from within the container, I would suggest simply installing it within the container, instead of trying to mount the required binaries and libraries into the container. This can be done in your container's `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM whatever

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install systemd
```

No need to mount `/bin/systemd` or `/lib/` with this solution.

Comment: I want to configure node's termination hook using the code in the container. Node termination hook is a systemd process of the node. How will the systemd installation in the container help?

Comment: Because the `systemd` package contains the `systemctl` binary that you've asked about in your question (and all the various libraries required as dependency).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, been stuck with this for sometime now. You mean to say if I install systemctl in the container i can still configure node's systemd scripts from inside the container. Will it require mounts?

Comment: Installed the systemctl, getting this. `root@nginx-deployment-98d4cfc5b-hngl6:/# systemctl
Failed to issue method call: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.`

Comment: Yes, if you want to control the `systemd` init process on the node, you'll probably need the `/var/run/dbus`, `/run/systemd` and probably also `/etc/systemd` mounts.

Comment: Have added those mounts, but the node is blocking the response to the container with the above error. ^

Comment: Haven't seen that one before. You might experiment a bit with starting your container with the `privileged` flag, and also the `hostPID` and/or `hostIPC` flags ([doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#podspec-v1-core))

Comment: Thanks a ton @helmbert It worked. systemctl complete output is not being allowed by the node but all the commands like systemctl status, systemctl enable for a single service is working just fine. thank you so much

Comment: Glad to hear that. What was it that ultimately did the trick? The `privileged` flag?

Comment: No i just tried the commands i wanted from systemctl and they all worked. I think running only `$ systemctl` returns a very huge `less` output, only that has the issue inside container.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where one of the lines in my Dockerfile was:
RUN apt-get install -y --reinstall systemd
but after docker restart, when I tried to use systemctl command. The output was:
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory.
I solved this issue by adding following to my docker-compose.yml:
volumes:
  - "/sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro"
It can be done also by:
sudo docker run -d -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro {other options}